# background-attachment: fixed for <img> with object-fit cover?

Tags: html, css

Is there a trick or workaround to make image with `object-fit:cover` and absolute positioning in parent to behave like `background-attachment: fixed` in css?

I want this:

```
<section>
    <img src="" style="object-fit: cover; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
</section>
```

to have same functionality as this:

```
<section style="background: url(..); background-attachment: fixed;">
<section>
```

Comment: Maybe background-size: cover; ?

Comment: @shai_sharakanski I updated the question with html, I'm asking how to make `img` behave like `background-attachment:fixed`

Comment: @TemaniAfif does it still work if there are multiple sections like this? Would that require messing with z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:fixed` combined with a `clip-path` trick can do it

```css
section {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 5px;
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/800" 
    style="object-fit: cover; 
           position: fixed;
           left:0;
           top:0;
           width: 100%; 
           height: 100%;">
</section>

<section 
  style="
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/800); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;">
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it work everywhere or some browsers do not support clip-path?

Comment: @Runnick only IE doesn't support clip-path but this isn't a suprise and it's a dead browser. All the other browsers support it